# Efficient for loops for Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes, X_ol and y_ol,with a shape of 29000 x 29 and 29000 x 21, and I'm running a nested for loop through this data to generate more data(as you'll see below). What I'm trying to achieve with this for loop is something like this:

```
    DataFrame X_ol                              DataFrame y_ol
    id     Date      c1      c2      c3         c1      c2      c3
    1      2000      0       1       1          0       1       1
    2      2001      1       0       1          1       0       1
    3      2002      1       1       0          1       1       0
    4      2003      1       1       1          1       1       1

    # (New DataFrame X)                         # (Second New DataFrame, y)
    id     Date      c1      c2      c3         c1      c2      c3 
    1      2000      0       0       1          0       1       0
    1      2000      0       1       0          0       0       1
    2      2001      0       0       1          1       0       0
    2      2001      1       0       0          0       0       1
    3      2002      0       1       0          1       0       0
    3      2002      1       0       0          0       1       0
    4      2003      0       1       1          1       0       0
    4      2003      1       0       1          0       1       0
    4      2003      1       1       0          0       0       1
```

so it looks at the y_ol dataframe row by row and for each cell value of 1 it creates a new row in dataframe X, with that cell switched off, and creates a new row in the y dataframe with the corresponding cell on and all other values on the same row in the y Dataframe will now be switched off.
I wrote this code that does it correctly, but takes so much time. 12+ minutes producing the 2 Data Frames of 60,000 rows, are there built in pandas functions/methods to use to make this more efficient or another method entirely that takes out the for loop?

```
for i in range(len(y_ol)):
    ab = y_ol.iloc[i].where(y_ol.iloc[i]==1)
    abInd = ab[ab==1.0].index
    for j in abInd:
        y_tmp = deepcopy(y_ol.iloc[i:i+1, :])
        y_ol[j][i] = 0
        conc = pd.concat([X_ol.iloc[i:i+1,:], y_ol.iloc[i:i+1, :]], axis=1)
        X = X.append(conc)
        y_tmp.iloc[:, :] = 0
        y_tmp[j] = 1
        y = y.append(y_tmp)
        y_ol[j][i] = 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: to be sure, columns c1, c2, and c3 are the same, row wise between X_ol and y_ol?

Comment: @Ben.T yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the new y_ol, you can use `stack` to after changing the 0 to with where. Then reset_index the level 1 that is actually the name of the column in y_ol with 1 originally.

```
df_ = y_ol.where(y_ol.eq(1)).stack().reset_index(level=1)
print (df_)
  level_1    0
0      c2  1.0
0      c3  1.0
1      c1  1.0
1      c3  1.0
2      c1  1.0
2      c2  1.0
3      c1  1.0
3      c2  1.0
3      c3  1.0
```

Use this column named level_1 and numpy broadcasting to compare it to the columns names of y_ol to get True/False. Change the type to `int` and build the new y_ol dataframe as wanted.

```
y_ol_new = pd.DataFrame((df_['level_1'].to_numpy()[:, None] 
                         == y_ol.columns.to_numpy()).astype(int),
                        columns=y_ol.columns)
print (y_ol_new)
   c1  c2  c3
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   0
3   0   0   1
4   1   0   0
5   0   1   0
6   1   0   0
7   0   1   0
8   0   0   1
```

Now for X_ol, you can `reindex` it with the index of df_ to duplicate rows. Then you just need to remove y_ol_new.

```
X_ol_new = X_ol.reindex(df_.index).reset_index(drop=True)
X_ol_new[y_ol_new.columns] -= y_ol_new
print (X_ol_new)
   id  Date  c1  c2  c3
0   1  2000   0   0   1
1   1  2000   0   1   0
2   2  2001   0   0   1
3   2  2001   1   0   0
4   3  2002   0   1   0
5   3  2002   1   0   0
6   4  2003   0   1   1
7   4  2003   1   0   1
8   4  2003   1   1   0
```

Comment: Hi, your solution worked nicely and in seconds, thank you so much

Comment: @TochiBedford glad it works for you, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I would process the dataframes by columns where a column in y_ol contains 1, and concat the temporary dataframes obtained per each column.

Assuming

```
x_ol = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],  'Date': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003],
                     'c1': [0, 1, 1, 1], 'c2': [1, 0, 1, 1], 'c3': [1, 1, 0, 1]}
y_ol = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0, 1, 1, 1], 'c2': [1, 0, 1, 1], 'c3': [1, 1, 0, 1]})
```

I would build the new dataframes that way:

```
cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
x_new = pd.concat((x_ol[y_ol[c] == 1].assign(**{c: 0}) for c in cols)).sort_values('id')
y_new = pd.concat((y_ol[y_ol[c] == 1].assign(**{x: 1 if x == c else 0 for x in cols})
                   for c in cols)).sort_index()
```

It gives as expected

```
print(x_new)

   id  Date  c1  c2  c3
0   1  2000   0   0   1
0   1  2000   0   1   0
1   2  2001   0   0   1
1   2  2001   1   0   0
2   3  2002   0   1   0
2   3  2002   1   0   0
3   4  2003   0   1   1
3   4  2003   1   0   1
3   4  2003   1   1   0
```

and

```
print(y_new)

   c1  c2  c3
0   0   1   0
0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   0
2   0   1   0
3   1   0   0
3   0   1   0
3   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but your method still makes use of for loops, which caused the slowness in the first place, final output is going to be about 60,000 rows and "for" loops take a dreadful amount of time. Thanks again

Comment: @TochiBedford the loop for here is on the column, not the rows, so efficiency-wise, it will be way faster than than your original solution :)